# PyQt5 - How to make cancel button with QinputDialog.getItems

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have this code, using PyQt5 QinputDialog in python , but when i run the program and click the cancel button it's goes to open my other window instead of closing the current window

```
pasanger = ('1', '2', '3', '4')
self.selection, self.ok = QInputDialog.getItem(self, "Choose the passanger", "Passanger",passanger, 0, False)
```

Does anyone know how to make the cancel button works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QInputDialog.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getItem). You can use the second return value (`self.ok` in your case) to check whether the user clicked `Ok` or `Cancel`.

Assuming you are running your snippet from within a `QWindow`:

```python
pasanger = ('1', '2', '3', '4')
self.selection, self.ok = QInputDialog.getItem(self, "Choose the passanger", "Passanger",passanger, 0, False)

if not self.ok:
    self.close()
else:
    # run your remaining code
```

(Also, you might want to check your spelling on passenger.)